# How to find out which label contains 'active' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got 4 labels that act as radio buttons. When a label is active it will have the class `active`. I want to find out which label has the `active` class when one of the labels is clicked. I've tried `hasClass()`, but that is executed before the classes are changed. Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem? Should I create a seperate method for every label?

```js
$("#elements").click(function() {
  if ($("#eventelement").hasClass("active")) {
    console.log("event activated")

  }
  if ($("#roleelement").hasClass("active")) {
    console.log("role activated")

  }
  // [...]
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="elements" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 20px">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="eventelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="event" id="elementoption1" autocomplete="off" checked> Event
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="roleelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="role" id="elementoption2" autocomplete="off"> Role
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="workelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="workingarea" id="elementoption3" autocomplete="off"> Working Area
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="calendarelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="calendar" id="elementoption4" autocomplete="off"> Calendar
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: To be sure. Do you have a separate method to Toggle the active class ?

Comment: @Zarif Check my answer; it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Code to check both `previous-active-label` and `current-active-label`***

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#elements label').on('click',function(){
    var prev = $('label.active').children('input[type="radio"]').val();
    var current = $(this).children('input[type="radio"]').val();
    $('#elements label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    alert("previous active label is "+prev);
    alert("current active label is "+current);
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
color:green;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="elements" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 20px">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="eventelement" style="width:25%">
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="event" id="elementoption1" autocomplete="off" checked> Event
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="roleelement" style="width:25%">
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="role" id="elementoption2" autocomplete="off"> Role
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="workelement" style="width:25%">
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="workingarea" id="elementoption3" autocomplete="off"> Working Area
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="calendarelement" style="width:25%">
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="calendar" id="elementoption4" autocomplete="off"> Calendar
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks. Works great.

Comment: @Zarif  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a class to find active option. You can just use `:checked` selector.

Here is working example.

```js
$("#elements label").click(function () {
    var currentValue = $("input[name=type]:checked").val();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
})
```

```css
label {
  color: blue;
}
label.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="elements" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 20px">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="eventelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="event" id="elementoption1" autocomplete="off"> Event
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="roleelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="role" id="elementoption2" autocomplete="off"> Role
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="workelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="workingarea" id="elementoption3" autocomplete="off"> Working Area
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="calendarelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="calendar" id="elementoption4" autocomplete="off"> Calendar
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The checked attribute stays in the first input element and does not change when I click another label. Any idea why? I suppose it is because of Bootstrap?

Comment: @Zarif Bootstrap usually doesnt change anything on HTML unless you use plugins, are you using plugins to manipulate forms design/etc?

Comment: No. If I click another label. It gets the `active` class, but the `checked` attribute is not added.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution inadvertently, wrapping the label selection in `setTimeout` delays it just enough to return the proper one.

```js
$("#elements").on("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var l = $("#elements label.active");
    console.log(l.get()[0].id);
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="elements" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 20px">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="eventelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="event" id="elementoption1" autocomplete="off" checked> Event
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="roleelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="role" id="elementoption2" autocomplete="off"> Role
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="workelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="workingarea" id="elementoption3" autocomplete="off"> Working Area
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="calendarelement" style="width:25%">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="calendar" id="elementoption4" autocomplete="off"> Calendar
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Do timeouts have any drawbacks?

Comment: I decided to use the other solution instead. Seems safer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to radio input change and check which one is selected:

```
$("#elements input").on("change", function() {
    var activeLabel = $("#elements input:checked").parent();
    console.log(activeLabel.attr('id') + ' activated');
});
```

Please note, one can change the selection using keyboard as well, therefor click is not enough.

Also on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqtf9jnq/6/).

Comment: Unless I'm severely mistaken, your code logs the previous selection, not the current one. Your fiddle does output a label, but the wrong one. Just add `.attr("id")`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qqtf9jnq/4/ (and the code in your answer, which is different from the fiddle, doesn't work for me either: `activeLabel` has a length of 0)

Comment: @ChrisG - quite correct, thanks. The answer is updated.